# AndroidStudio SVN considerations... Files to ignore? How to import a new project? etc

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, intellij-idea, version-control

I am new with AndroidStudio, i have readed already the oficial documentation, but i can't find which files i must ignore when versioning a AndroidStudio project...

https://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Also i need to know how to upload a new project to my svn repository with AndroidStudio. I thought that there is a "import" button or something located in VCS tab but i can't find it. Also can't find any documentation about this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://littlecodingmachine.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/how-to-check-out-an-svn-project-with-android-studio/) out to see how to import a project.
However I found the built-in VSC very tricky and ended up using tortoise SVN instead. 
I marked the following as ignored.

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

**Note**: The built-in VCS will not ignore any file and will import/export the whole directory.